# find item in col a then find sub item col b give col c data

Tags: excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that inputs meal from drop down then it is looking for the nutrition information from another sheet that has the meal in col a and then the nutrients in col b the amounts in col c this is the item i want below is what the data page looks like: 
Hamburger Soup
    Nutrient    amount  unit
    Calories    208 
    fat 7   g
    fiber   3   g
    carbs   23  g
    sodium  539 mg
    potassium   672 mg
    sugars  5   g
    Vit. A  27  mg
    Vit. C  8   mg
    Vit. K  14  mg
    calcium 44  mg
    iron    2   mg
    protien 13  g
So i am trying to get this information to populate on the first spreadsheet which is menu and these are on nutrients. I have tried using vlookup and index and match but i keep getting errors of the wrong info. Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you be more clear on how exactly the spreadsheet is formatted? It is hard to get a sense of what you are asking from the question.

Comment: This is basically tracking  food and breaking down the nutritional information the trouble i am having is the nutritional information is in a worksheet of its own that has a heading which is the recipe /meal name then the next column has the nutrients names like calories and calcium and sodium then the next column has the amount ( this is the column that i need ) what is happening is that i am only pulling the very first information  from the first recipe I need to be able to scan the first column and find the meal name and then pull that sub infomation

Comment: So is the format look like [this](https://imagebin.ca/v/3J3W9wyqCwBT)? If so, what exactly are you doing with the data, finding a number based on meal type and nutrient type? On a side note, you should have a more clear visualization of the spreadsheet. Most people won't go through the effort of trying to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Your image is close not sure how to get you an image of the page but row 1 column A cell 1 hamburger soup row 2 column B start at cell 2: Nutrient amount unit
row 3 column b start at cell 2 :Calories 208 
fat 7 g
these go down for 13 rows and cells

Comment: I would write a VBA script function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial an error and figured it out I had to add an extra row to identify what row the meal was on then I utilized this following formula utilizing an if statement i checked to see if the meal location was empty if so I placed a blank if it was populated it then put the row into a hidden column and cell. then I did an offset command looking at the nutrient sheet and then went down the number of rows for the nutrient and then read the 2nd column. this is the formula "if T19="","",offset(nutrients!$a$2,v19+1,2) this populated the correct fields and space. Thank you for all of the information that you had given.